# Some help diagram a use case with Visual Paradigm

Tags: uml, actor, use-case, visual-paradigm

I am modeling a use case in UML using Visual Paradigm CE but I have a few doubts regarding my model. Take a look to the picture below:

[image]

This are the rules I am trying to represent with that model:

- There are 3 user types: Superadmin, Admin and Executive
- There is a functionality called: Admin User
- Admin User is divided in 4 basic actions: Create, Read, Update and Delete
- Superadmin has all the power (can do anything) while Admin only has a few permissions (in this case Create User)
- Executive can only perform a few actions within the system: Create User and Delete User

Taking this as a starting point, the diagram is correct? How would to do? I must say this is a example use case just to get the correct way to represent the relation between diagram elements.

**Update**: Based on the answer by **@thomas-kilian** I have made this two diagrams:

[image: including CRUD in Admin User UC]
[image: extends CRUD from Admin User UC]

Comment: In most cases you can combine all the CRUD scenarios into a single use case such as "Manage Users". I would not model those low level security requirements on the use case level.

Comment: @GeertBellekens yes but then I could have troubles describing the UC as it should have several actions and I am not clear at all on how to achieve this description

Comment: Use use case scenarios to describe the different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need use case "Admin User"? Maybe the following diagram will suit your needs:

[image]

If you really have behavior in 'Admin User', not contained in the other use cases, then you can keep it, but I would use a consistent naming convention, e.g. verb + noun, and thus rename 'Admin User' to 'Administer Users'.

Diagram 1 is possible. In this case, SuperAdmin can reach the 'Create User' functionality both directly (inherited from Admin) and via Admin User. Apparently, Admin User has multiple alternative flows. Create User is included in one alternative flow, Update User in another, etc. This is fine.

Diagram 2 is also possible. In this case, SuperAdmin can only reach the 'Create User' functionality via Admin User.

Diagram 3 is possible, but tricky. Actors 'Admin' and 'Executive' are associated to so-called "extending use cases" Create User and Delete User. An extending use case typically only defines a use case fragment, which is to be inserted at a particular point in the extended use case (Admin User). But since actors Admin and Executive directly execute use cases Create User and Delete User, these use cases must describe complete flows of events. If you manage to define the flows of events of the extending use cases such, that they are suited both for direct execution and for insertion at the extension points inside use case Admin User, then it's fine.

Comment: Thx for the tip around naming convention I use those ones as an examples (will not be used on the real diagram). See the mainly problem I am having is because I am working in a web application. The application will have two main areas: `frontend` and `backend`. At this moment it will have five main roles: `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, `ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLE_EXECUTIVE` and two more. Those roles will have access to the backend but not to all the areas so I need to draw that in a diagram so I can discuss with the rest of the team. So, how would you model that?

Comment: I have added a diagram to my answer to show how I would model it.

Comment: Great, I like your approach and I will use it now regarding diagram tool I am using Visual Paradigm 13.0 CE, I have to many UC, there is any way to divide those UC by its functionalities? For example one main diagram saying "Administer User" then on click go to a expanded view of this case containing a diagram like yours? Any idea on this one? Take a look to [this](http://content.screencast.com/users/ReynierPM/folders/Snagit/media/7314fea9-19ee-42e4-9b57-dd81792a2aed/01.26.2016-00.16.png) then you will know what I am talking about.

Comment: You may create a package diagram containing a package symbol labeled "User Administration" and when you open the package, show a use case diagram. I don't know if this is possible in Visual Paradigm. If you need more info, please raise a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on whom you are asking. So here are my 5 cent:

- Avoid include/extend as they are a sign of functional decomposition (if at all: extend in your diagram is the wrong way around)
- CRUD UCs are always borderline. I would in this case not try to introduce the `Admin User` as it does not seem to be a valid UC while the CRUD parts are.
- As you connected the actors the Super Admin can do anything, but the admin can only create. That does not seem to be logical. If you have a generalized actor, this inherits all access to UCs of the general one. Means: you don't need to repeat the connections to UC (unless you add some constraints).

Comment: Ok, take a look to the edit I made on the OP and based on that which is the right representation? Or again give me another 5 more cents :p lol

Comment: Well, you reversed the extend, but you did not pay attention to what I said. The include variant is complete nonsense :-p . Means Admin User will involve all CRUD steps.

Comment: I think the UML spec leaves room for the interpretation, that an included use case may be included in an alternative flow and hence will not be executed in every scenario.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl See my first bullet point. I/E are two very bad concepts in UML and stem from a technical/functional approach which some guys with mainly techie background have introduced. They are evil (!) and will cause harm and confusion. I have never ever seen a case where you really need them.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl And no: the UML spec states "An Include relationship specifies that a UseCase contains the behavior defined in another UseCase."

Comment: @ThomasKilian : I think include is useful. The primary use of the Include relationship is for reuse of common parts. In this case, there isn't any reuse, but still, include is not harmful here. The alternative would be: one use case with multiple alternative flows. But there is not much difference between one use case with 4 flows and 4 separate use cases, as long as each use case yields an observable result that is of value to the actor.

Comment: @ThomasKilian : About the UML spec: Yes, but what does "contain" mean? I think that if the included use case is included in an alternative flow, then the behavior of the including use case "contains" the behavior of the included use case (though not in every possible scenario).

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl If you reuse a UC then it will not represent some individual added value. So again: include is wrong. We will likely not clarify this in the comments. It took me many years to really understand it. Bittner/Spence helped very, very much.

Comment: @ThomasKilian : I hope it will take you less time to really *really* understand it :-)  Each of the five use cases in this example have added value to the actor, even the ones that are reused.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl You mean like "Admin user". Yes. Very valuable.